# DB2 - Find Mismatch - fetch query

Tags: sql, db2

I had two tables,

1. first - individualstock - for each stock - each row - product id is FK ,
2. second - Product - for each product - each row. have quantity column.

and naturally, the count of stock in stock table is equal to quantity in product table.
and I want to find the mismatch.

and I wrote a query as below,

```
select a.stockid from stock a , product b where a.productid = b.productid and sum(a.quantity)<> b.quantity with ur.
```

but its throwing an error. use of function in appropiate plz.

Is there any other way to solve this.

In the same time is there any way to print `b.quantity` and `sum(a.quantity)` as well inaddition to `a.stockid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following query:

```
select s.stockid, p.productid, p.quantity
from stock s join
     product p
     on p.productid = s.productid
group by p.productid, p.quantity 
having sum(s.quantity) <> p.quantity;
```

Use the `having` clause to compare aggregated results, not the `where` clause.

Comment: Hi Gordon thats rocking, Perfect Output.

Comment: In the same time is there any way to print  p.quantity  and sum(s.quantity) as well inaddition to s.stockid

Comment: @AProgrammer . . . Of course.  The only reason I left them out of the `select` is because your query did not have them.